# Get reponse message in Node using Request library?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, request

My backend server has the following code using Express:

```
router.post('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.end(res.writeHead(200, "custom message");
});
```

When I make this post request in Node.js using Request library how do I get the "custom message"?

```
var request = require("request");
request.post(options, function(error, response, body) {
  console.log(response.statusCode); //works
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.headers)); //doesn't have my custom message 
});
```

In c# I was able to get this message in the statusDecription property, how does it work in Request library?

Edit:
Solved with the following code:

```
router.post('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.end(res.writeHead(200, {"test": "custom message"});
});
```

then

```
var request = require("request");
request.post(options, function(error, response, body) {
  console.log(response.headers["test"]);  
});
```

Comment: Your second example should work: it should log `custom message`. Maybe you've changed your server code and just forgot to restart your server?

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I did make a small typo and it's funny how I solved a typo by making another typo -.-

Answer (score -1):

From the `http.ServerResponse` API:

> **`response.writeHead(statusCode[, statusMessage][, headers])`**
>
> Sends a response header to the request. The status code is a 3-digit HTTP status code, like 404. The last argument, headers, are the response headers. Optionally one can give a human-readable `statusMessage` as the second argument.

The `response` argument in the `request` callback is an instance of `http.ServerResponse`. What you're looking for is in the `response.statusMessage`.

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse

Comment: response.statusMessage returns undefined. What you gave is from Node's user manual. I'm not using that... I'm using Request Library from https://github.com/request/request